# Generate this assembly from a c program

Tags: assembly, c

I want to generate this assembly code:

```
mov ecx, <absolute address of func1>
call ecx
```

How can I write and compile C code which generates this code?

Comment: Is this about reverse engineering or about software engineering?

Comment: In fact i have reversed a program which contains that and i am wondering if it is possible to do that in c

Comment: (1) This is not clear enough. It depends a lot on the compiler, optimization level, and whether you're willing to use `__asm__`. (2) It seems that you're having an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You want specifically `ecx` or any register that may do the job?

Comment: Spécificaly ecx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the compiler will generate the call using the address of the function directly. But since in your case it uses a register, it reminds me of C++ vtables. 
So in C, how about calling a pointer to a function? Something like this:

```
void (*fptr)(void);
void foo(void) {
   /* some code */
}
fptr = foo;
(*fptr)();   /* <-- your indirect call generated here */
```